# Java 10 replacement for sun MonitoredHost class

Tags: java, jvm, java-10

What class or complete jar file is replacement for sun.jvmstat.monitor MonitoredHost class in Java 10, because from Java 9 sun.* package is mostly unsupported?

Problem:
My application is intended to be single instance, in a way that when the application is already started, and user tried to start it again, it won't just close second application that user tried to start, it would also put first application in focus. 
Till now my application used sun MonitoredHost class to go through list of active processes in search of same applications started in JVMs, so if it finds one, first one would go in focus, and the second one would close.

I have one solution of manipulation with multiple lock files, but I would prefer a more cleaner side of code through something specifically designed for monitoring JVMs.

Comment: Which system and what kind of application? Server applications usually use a server socket which they have to create anyway, but it seems your are talking about a desktop application, right?

Comment: In principle, there’s [`Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/awt/Desktop.html) with the [`AppReopenedListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/awt/desktop/AppReopenedListener.html) for platforms which support it, otherwise, the [Attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?jdk.attach-summary.html) is the standard way to find running JVMs since Java 6…

Comment: Lock files can commonly used too.

Answer (score 1):

It's still there, but it's in the `jdk.internal.jvmstat` module.  When you build/run, you'll need to include something like:

```
--add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
```